# How would I copy entire rows within a table and change one value?

Tags: sql

```
insert into user 
    (user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, admin_user, primary_user)
select * 
from pnet_user 
where account_id='1';
```

But now I want to change 1 to 2 on the inserted entries. But now I want to change 1 to 3 on the inserted entries. But now I want to change 1 to .... on the inserted entries. But now I want to change 1 to 1000 on the inserted entries.

It will copy and write down 1000 times (only changing id ).

Do you understand ? Sorry for my poor English ! Thank you very much !

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, ...? You can write a stored procedure for this. If you need to increment by one every time, a simple `for` loop will be enough

Comment: also... are you using some front end language (PHP, Java, Python...)? That may be another solution

Comment: So you basically want to re-insert the same data and just change the user-id?

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what you mean;

If you want the first 1000 users why not write;

```
WHERE account_id <= 1000
```

If you want all users;

Have no `WHERE` clause.

If you want the user inserted via a parameter (user input);

```
DECLARE @ID int
SET @ID = 1;

WHERE account_id = @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into user 
    (user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, admin_user, primary_user)
select * 
from pnet_user 
where account_id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

The `SELECT`-part may return multiple rows at once. (I presume account_id is not really a string but a number).
Besides, I would strongly recommend to type out the column names in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into user (user_id,account_id,user_type_cd,name,e_mail_addr,login_failure_cnt,admin_user,primary_user) select * from pnet_user
```

and you can specifu column name also instead of *

```
insert into user (user_id,account_id,user_type_cd,name,e_mail_addr,login_failure_cnt,admin_user,primary_user) select id,ac_id .... from pnet_user
```

Answer (score 0):

If account_id is numeric, Just change the where clause

```
  Insert user (user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, 
       name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, 
       admin_user, primary_user)
  Select user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, 
       name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, 
       admin_user, primary_user
  From pnet_user where account_id 
       Between 1 and 1000
```

If account_id really is a string, then change it to a number

```
  Insert user (user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, 
       name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, 
       admin_user, primary_user)
  Select user_id, account_id, user_type_cd, 
       name, e_mail_addr, login_failure_cnt, 
       admin_user, primary_user
  From pnet_user where Cast(account_id as integer) 
       Between 1 and 1000
```